# Chronyc long waitsync time if I don't reinstall it

Tags: software-installation, chrony

"chronyc waitsync" takes a very long time, and I don't know exactly if the command times out or does it just take a very long time to sync.
But, reinstalling chrony fixes the issue. Do you have any ideas about what could be wrong?

**EDIT**

Here are outputs of `systemctl status chronyd`, `chronyc tracking` and `chronyc sources` before and after reinstallation:

BEFORE

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ systemctl status chronyd
● chronyd.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ chronyc tracking
Reference ID    : 0.0.0.0 ()
Stratum         : 0
Ref time (UTC)  : Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 1970
System time     : 0.000000000 seconds fast of NTP time
Last offset     : +0.000000000 seconds
RMS offset      : 0.000000000 seconds
Frequency       : 0.000 ppm fast
Residual freq   : +0.000 ppm
Skew            : 0.000 ppm
Root delay      : 0.000000 seconds
Root dispersion : 0.000000 seconds
Update interval : 0.0 seconds
Leap status     : Not synchronised
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ chronyc sources
210 Number of sources = 4
MS Name/IP address         Stratum Poll Reach LastRx Last sample
===============================================================================
^+ corona.gora.si                2   6     0    16  +4687ns[ +427us] +/- 5212us
^* 2.pool.chrony.eu              1   6     0    16    +45us[ +467us] +/- 3055us
^- 3.pool.chrony.eu              2   6     0    16   +418us[ +418us] +/- 4080us
^- guitarvoodoolab.si            2   6     0    15   -388us[ -388us] +/- 9073us
```

AFTER

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ systemctl status chronyd
● chronyd.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ chronyc tracking
Reference ID    : 84.255.251.188 (2.pool.chrony.eu)
Stratum         : 2
Ref time (UTC)  : Thu Jul  8 12:44:26 2021
System time     : 0.000000130 seconds slow of NTP time
Last offset     : +0.000447990 seconds
RMS offset      : 0.000447990 seconds
Frequency       : 0.000 ppm fast
Residual freq   : +41.937 ppm
Skew            : 1000000.000 ppm
Root delay      : 0.004340 seconds
Root dispersion : 40.276096 seconds
Update interval : 2.0 seconds
Leap status     : Normal
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ chronyc sources
210 Number of sources = 4
MS Name/IP address         Stratum Poll Reach LastRx Last sample
===============================================================================
^- stanjel.ung.si                2   6    17    52  +4460us[+4908us] +/-   67ms
^* 2.pool.chrony.eu              1   6    17    50    -31us[ +417us] +/- 2234us
^+ 3.pool.chrony.eu              2   6    17    52   +304us[ +752us] +/- 3084us
^- cad.lecad.fs.uni-lj.si        2   6    17    52   -834us[ -386us] +/-   22ms
```

PS: I am trying to create a Raspberry PI image from chroot. That's why reinstalling is a problem - because I want the image to work without doing any additional work (I dont't want to reinstall chrony every time after flashing to SD card.)

Comment: Provide some more information. What is the status of chronyd (`systemctl status chronyd`) before and after reinstallaion? What does following commands return before and after reinstallation: `chronyc tracking`, `chronyc sources`.

Comment: @nobody I have updated the question with the information you requested

Comment: In a manual for chronyc it says: "chronyc is a command-line interface program which can be used to monitor chronyd’s performance and to change various operating parameters whilst it is running." Therefore, I do not know how chronyc is working at all, as your output shows chronyd is not running. It seems that at installation it sets up the time, but that is not enough. You need to have chronyd up an running. I would recommend you make sure chronyd is running (systemctl enable chronyd; systemctl start chronyd).

Comment: @nobody If I run 'systemctl enable chronyd' I get an error message "Operation failed: No such file or directory" and if I run 'systemctl start chronyd', I get a message "Failed to start chronyd.service: Unit chronyd.service not found." I have looked in a few folders where services should be located, but I didn't find the chronyd.service file, which probably results in "No such file or directory" error

Comment: Oops. Try `chrony` instead of `chronyd`in systemctl commands.

Comment: @nobody this showed that the service is working. Also, the problem disappeared and I don't know what exactly fixed it.

Comment: So as nobody else can answer, maybe delete the question.